# How to redirect after login in scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I am writing a program in scrapy to login in scrape same data from a website.  It appears to be logging in correctly, as far as I can tell, but when it logs in it redirects to a webpage I do not want it to scrape.  I need it to go to this webpage, https://www.starcitygames.com/myaccount/.  How can I get my program to go to that page after login?

```
import scrapy
from ..items import NameItem

class LoginSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "LoginSpider"
    start_urls = ["https://www.starcitygames.com/login"]

    def parse(self, response):

        return scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(
        response,
        formdata={'ex_usr_email': 'username', 'ex_usr_pass': 'password'},
        callback=self.after_login
     )

    def after_login(self, response):
        item = NameItem()
        item["Name"] = response.css("div.column_data::text").get()
        return item
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to split into two steps:

```
def after_login(self, response):
    yield scrapy.Request(url="https://www.starcitygames.com/myaccount/", callback=self.parse_data)

def parse_data(self, response):
    item = NameItem()
    item["Name"] = response.css("div.column_data::text").get()
    return item
```